# How to suppress Null output when redirecting outputs to separate Notebook/Window?

Tags: programming, notebooks

I've been redirecting outputs to a separate notebook using this simple code to modify the $Post variable:

```
nbout = CreateDocument[]

$Post = Function[expr, SelectionMove[nbout, Next, Cell];
   NotebookWrite[nbout, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@expr, "Output"]]];
```

This works nicely except for code that does normally not generate output, i.e. lines with `";"`.
For those lines, a `Null` output is generated in the `nbout` notebook.

Is there a simple way to suppress this output?

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You can write: `If[expr === Null, ...]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thank you ! This works.